Kraft setup with controller and broker on seprate node while using SSL for encryption and authentication
I am trying to test kraft setup in individual mode where controller and broker has their own respective properties file and running seperate node . I just want to keep it simple by using ssl for encryption  and authentication both at the moment  . No Sasl method / mechanism for authentication . Does anyone have tested this type of setup , any sample for properties file would be really helpful.
I have drafted require configuration for respective  controller and broker  configuration file ,
i guess this should work for having 3 broker and 3 controller .
Super.user field on both properties file should holds the cert dn details for rest of other broker and controller node  .
My assumption is server with broker role communicate with other broker so each should have cert dn details to their respective broker.properties file .
Servers with controller  role should have cert DN details for other controller node , also cert dn details for broker node as well  .
Reason is , During cluster communication , All controller communicate with each other controller for forming quorum , in same way all broker communicate with other broker node ,also broker do communicate with controller also for quorum metadata details . I think it is rare when controller would be initiating connection with broker , rather it is always be from broker to controller connection , this is the reason even if broker have cert dn details in super.user parameter for other nodes which has process role as broker it should be sufficient enough , broker do not need to have cert DN details of controller node .However vice versa controller should have cert dn details of other server which has process role as broker .
Please help me with if anyone has already done this kind of setup for kraft and do agree with assumption described above
Here is configuration details which i Will set  for three controller and broker setup and expect this is standard one for forming kraft cluster . controller will form the quorum using ssl as authentication and encryption similarly broker will form cluster and will be communicate to controller using ssl as authentication and encryption .
`


process.Roles=broker
node.id=1
listeners=SSL://broker:9094
listener.security.protocol.map=BROKER:SSL,CONTROLLER:SSL
inter.broker.listener.name=BROKER
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=keystore-password
ssl.key.password=key-password
ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=truststore-password
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
super.users:User:"CN=broker1,OU=ServiceUsers,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown";User:"CN=broker2,OU=ServiceUsers,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown";User:"CN=broker3,OU=ServiceUsers,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown"



process.roles=controller
node.id=2
listeners=CONTROLLER://controller:9093
listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER:SSL
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=keystore-password
ssl.key.password=key-password
ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=truststore-password
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
super.users:User:User:"CN=controller1,OU=ServiceUsers,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown";User:"CN=controller2,OU=ServiceUsers,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown";User:"CN=controller3,OU=ServiceUsers,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown";"CN=broker1,OU=ServiceUsers,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown";User:"CN=broker2,OU=ServiceUsers,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown";User:"CN=broker3,OU=ServiceUsers,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown"

`
